# Is writer an atomic method?

Tags: java, multithreading, file-io, atomic

I want to write some strings to a file. So, I used *BufferedWriter* class. Since many threads tend to write to that file, I want to know whether *write* and *writeLine* methods are atomic or not.

Also, I want the program to write the output to multiple files, and 100 lines per file (say file.txt0,file.txt1,...). For example

```
public class Main {
    static ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    BufferedWriter bw;
    public class myWriter implements Runnable {
        String str;
        myWriter (String str) {
            this.str = str;
        }
        public void run() {
            bw.write(str);
            bw.writeLine();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new  FileWriter("train.txt"));
        for (String arg: args)
            exec.execute(new myWriter(arg));
        exec.awaitTermination(100000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me? If they are not atomic, how can I make them atomic and avoid collision?

Answer (score 6):

Nope, those are not atomic.

If you want multliple writes to the same file, use [FileLocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html).

```
try {
    // Get a file channel for the file
    File file = new File("filename");
    FileChannel channel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw").getChannel();

    // Use the file channel to create a lock on the file.
    // This method blocks until it can retrieve the lock.
    FileLock lock = channel.lock();

    // Try acquiring the lock without blocking. This method returns
    // null or throws an exception if the file is already locked.
    try {
        lock = channel.tryLock();
    } catch (OverlappingFileLockException e) {
        // File is already locked in this thread or virtual machine
    }

    // Release the lock
    lock.release();

    // Close the file
    channel.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: nice work. If I want it to write the outputs to multiple files, 100lines per file, what can I do?

Comment: @emab, that depends. You'll have to edit your question with more details of what (exactly) you want to do (:

Comment: @Marcelo is the example clear? imagine the files are going to be train.txt0 , train.txt1 ,...

Comment: how to test this?

Answer (score 5):

The code below is source code from jdk6,
it's the implementation of write in `BufferedWriter`，cause there's a `synchronized` in the function body, I think the `write()` in `BufferedWriter` is thread safe.  Btw, `write(String)` is implemented by calling `write(String,int,int)`.

```
public void write(String s, int off, int len) throws IOException {

    synchronized (lock) {

        ensureOpen();

        int b = off, t = off + len;

        while (b < t) {

            int d = min(nChars - nextChar, t - b);
            s.getChars(b, b + d, cb, nextChar);
            b += d;
            nextChar += d;

            if (nextChar >= nChars)
                flushBuffer();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That makes each write atomic, but the OP's code still has a concurrency issue when calling `bw.write(str); bw.writeLine();`.

Comment: @assylias That is not the only issue - the flushToBuffer ends up writing to the file. So if a concurrent thread were to read the file, it could read partial data.

Answer (score 3):

You can use FileLocks but there can be expensive.

Personally, I would use an ordinary object lock. e.g.

```
synchronized(bufferedWriter) {
  bufferedWriter.write stuff
  bufferedWriter.write more stuff
}
```

Comment: But here the bufferedWriter must be final. My bufferedWriter is not final, because it opens a new file every 100 line of output.

Comment: In that case you need an object which is `final` which you can use.  This should also lock around any re-openning of the file.

Answer (score 1):

NGloom is right, the following is a thread dump of a part of a program that does concurrent access to `BufferredWriter.append()` method (Oracle JDK 7 runtime) which uses no syncronization whatsoever on the method body. It's pretty clear that the implementaion of `BufferredWriter.append()` uses a monitor on the instance of the BufferredWriter object, so it is thread safe. However i can't find anything about thread safety [on the related java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) and thus the API does not make any such gurantees, as such implementations could vary? Furthermore the fact that `Writer.write()` is thread safe does not prevent another writer that wraps a different `OutputStream` object to the same file to attempt to write concurrently to it, which is not safe.

```
ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f358c002800 nid=0x3e66 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f360bdfb000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:220)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000760da06d8> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
    at java.io.Writer.append(Writer.java:227)
    at ...


ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f358c001000 nid=0x3e65 waiting for monitor entry [0x00007f360befc000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED (on object monitor)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(BufferedWriter.java:220)
    - waiting to lock <0x0000000760da06d8> (a java.io.OutputStreamWriter)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
    at java.io.Writer.append(Writer.java:227)
    at ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, BufferedWriter is thread safe. See snippet below. While writing the content synchronized block ensures the thread safety.

```
public void write(int c) throws IOException {
    synchronized (lock) {
        ensureOpen();
        if (nextChar >= nChars)
            flushBuffer();
        cb[nextChar++] = (char) c;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqJsI.jpg)